# Get objects from database of date between yesterday and today

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema.

```
const dish = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: string,
    },
        createdAt: {
        type: Date,
    },
)
```

I want to get the dishes that are created between yesterday 12AM to today's 12AM.

Comment: So what have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const dish = await Dish.aggregate([
 {
    $match: {
        $and: [
            { createdAt: { $lt: new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0))}},
            { createdAt: { $gte: new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0) - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)}}
       ]
     }
   }
]);
```

Edited:
Here is the explanation.

`new Date()` give you a date like `2022-11-15T22:14:00.000+00:00` but `new Date().setHours(0,0,0)` will set the values to 12AM but also gives you value in millisecond like `1668449700000`.

Your createdAt has value in date like `2022-11-15T22:14:00.000+00:00`. Using `{ $lt: new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0)}}` it will try to compare value between a **date** and a **integer** [`2022-11-15T22:14:00.000+00:00` , `1668449700000`] so you will get a wrong result.

So you need to put that into a new Date() to get the value in Date so that the `$lt` can compare properly. `new Date(new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0))}` will be equal to `new Date(1668449700000)` which will give you a date value and the `$lt` will also work properly.

As for the second condition, `24 * 60 * 60 * 1000` is 1 day in millisecond. So I've subtracted that to get the millisecond of yesterday's 12AM.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. I tried using `{ createdAt: { $lt: (new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0)}}` to get dates before 12AM but it didn't work so I got stuck. Can you give more explanation?